# Accessing text files from another project with NET Core (.NET Standard 1.5)

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

I have a console project A (NET Core App 1.0) that references a library B (.NET Standard 1.5).

The library (B) contains a bunch of text files that I need to load from the application.

The text files aren't copied to the output folder of project A, and this leaves only one option to load them with relative paths that are IMHO too weak.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: This is a very vague question... You're basically asking "how do I find the path to some files that my project uses". There as many possible answers but you'll probably need to copy the files to the output of A or some known location because projects don't exist anymore once you publish

Comment: You console project and any reference libraries are all run in the same path, and as @VictorHurdugaci noted, project doesn't exist after it's published.  You'll need to come up with a means of managing your text files outside of the project.